# Authentication using passport in node js application

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I want to setup passport.js for authentication in my node.js,express,mongoose application i have followed many examples on internet but got stuck with every one because still dont understand the flow of passport.js processing.
Any help with step by step setup, describing flow of the application would really help me understanding the concepts better.

Comment: I just had a look at passport.js and I personally do not see the benefit of using passport.js over writing a few lines authentication code yourself.

Comment: why is that ??? it provides you functions to authenticate and maintain sessions.... so user management becomes handy.

Comment: Well, it is using mongoose, which is nice and simple. You put password.js in as middleware and configure your strategy on how authentication should work. Why do you need a framework for that? I have a nice article for you which explains to you how to implement such an authentication system without the unneccessary overhead. http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/stop-storing-passwords-already/

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the following simple example.
https://github.com/kulor/passportjs-express-example

If you have questions, please let me know.

And please, don't reinvent the wheel. ;)

Comment: Your answer consists only of some link. If that links is not valid anymore your answer will be useless. Please include more information.